# Angular: setErrors not working inside loop

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I have a `FormArray` whose fields I want to validate at once. I'm iterating over the `FormArray` and for each element (`FormGroup`), I'm checking a condition, disabling the valid `FormGroup`s to avoid the user changing it and setting error to a specific `FormControl` inside the `FormGroup`.

Below is my code. `rows` is the `FormArray`.

```
response.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.detailName.valid && item.detailNo.valid)
        (<FormArray>this.detailForm.get('rows')).at(index).disable({
            onlySelf: true
        });
    else if (!(item.detailName.valid && item.detailNo.valid))
        if (!!item.detailName.value && !item.detailNo.value)
            this.detailForm.get(['rows', index, 'detailName']).setErrors({
                'invalidValue': true
            });
        else
            this.detailForm.get(['rows', index, 'detailNo']).setErrors({
                'invalidValue': true
            });
});
```

The error is not set as intended. That control is shown as `VALID` if I `console.log` it.

**Update:** Wrapped it by a `setTimeout` and it worked.

Comment: I don't know if it's related to the problem, but the condition at 7th row is never executed

Comment: Why not? I'm checking if value exists (not "") and it works.

Comment: Ops, sorry I read "valid" in place of "value"

Answer (score 4):

It's happening because you're setting validators inside `OnInit` hook. When Angular places the controls inside the view, it re-runs validators and thus removes the errors which you have set.

Here's [a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-effhdt?file=app/app.component.ts) which works around this behavior by using `AfterViewInit` hook. The code is also wrapped in a `setTimeout` call to avoid `ExpressionChangedAfterChecked` errors.

I personally disagree with this behavior and there's an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19465) for it, so you cat track that.